# Как можно создать ссылку на список в Perl?

Tags: perl

Пытался получить ссылку на список используя конструкцию:

```
\('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Но в итоге создал ссылку на `'d'`

Пытался таким образом:

```
my @arr = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
\@arr
```

Получилась ссылка на массив.

**Можно ли создать ссылку на список?**

Comment: `['a', 'b']` даст тебе ссылку на анонимный массив

Comment: Нет, не прошёл. Просто может кто-то захочет создать ссылку на список. А в вашем примере создается ссылка на анонимный аррэй. Ну и пусть. Важно  то, что ссылку на список создать нельзя. См. ответ.

Comment: хм. ну ладно. наверное, раз так, мне не стоит напоминать тебе про [comma operator](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steven_haryanto/2012/09/the-comma-operator.html)... :)

Comment: я так хотел намекнуть на то, что в первом "листинге", в скалярном контексте, нет никакого списка

Comment: да, поэтому ``как в перле создать ссылку на список?`` не имеет никакого смысла. То же можно сделать, используя массивы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Да и особого значение это не имеет, потому что вы можете добиться того же результата, используя массивы.

Answer (score 1):

Такой конструкции как `список` - в перле не существует. Для этого есть массив.

понятие `список` существует только тогда, когда вы передаёте что-то в фукнцию или возвращаете из неё.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно:

```
my $arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```